# Extend a set of functions $\mathscr{F}$ to a basis by operating on the elements of $\mathscr{F}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\mathscr{F} = \{f_i\}_{i=1}^N$ is a finite-dimensional set of functions contained in an infinite-dimensional space $\mathscr{H}$, i.e. $\mathscr{F} \subset \mathscr{H}$. Suppose $\mathscr{H}$ is equipped with an inner-product operation.

My question is the following. Can I extend the set $\mathscr{F}$ to a basis of $\mathscr{H}$ by simply operating on the $N$ functions $f_i$?

Or, in different terms: Let $f$ be any element in $\mathscr{H}$. Then, can I guarantee existence of a set of mappings $\mathcal{I}_j$ such that $f$ can be written as
$$ f = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i f_i + \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} \alpha_j \mathcal{I}_j(f_i),$$
for all $j$, with $\{\alpha_i\}\subset\mathbb{R}$? Or maybe I need extra assumptions on either $\mathscr{F}$ or $\mathscr{H}$? Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a particular application of this you have in mind?

Comment: @G.Chiusole I don't really know if this will be helpful but, function approximation would be the ultimate aim. Thanks.

Comment: Can I use the orthogonal complement of the subspace associated with the closed span of $\mathscr{F}$?